# Convert multidimensional array to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I got an numpy array looking like this:

```
0.716524    0.76476     0.734421    0.699913
0.708502    0.659577    0.646064    0.693093
0.749121    0.695317    0.675748    0.72938
0.68869     0.711581    0.614649    0.654494
0.651646    0.67847     0.655275    0.63885
0.765029    0.685263    0.646114    0.743514
0.7615      0.76907     0.728695    0.746114
0.682806    0.671888    0.6394      0.677168
...
```

and want to convert it to a pandas dataframe. I know you can convert one-dimensional arrays with

`pd.Dataframe(array, columns=["name"])`

But how would I do this in my case? And is it possible to name the columns dynamically if the size varies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame` constructor and for new columns names if dont know number of them is possible use [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
pd.Dataframe(array).add_prefix('Name')
```